# What is the Ken Thompson Hack?

Tags: c, compiler

I read some stuff like [cm bell labs](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html) but i couldn't get it all. How does it work really? What is the logic in that?

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/184874/is-ken-thompsons-compiler-hack-still-a-threat

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Reflections on Trusting Trust](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf) is a lecture by Ken Thompson in which he explains the hack. Briefly:

- he hacked `/bin/login` to introduce a backdoor.
- he did this by hacking the compiler to introduce the backdoor into a binary whenever it detected that it was compiling the `login` source code.
- he also hacked the compiler to introduce the backdoor-producing code into the *compiler* whenever it detected it was compiling that.

His point was that you might think "I don't trust this binary, I'll build it from source" but now you're in a state of recursive paranoia. If you don't trust the binary, why do you trust the compiler binary? You don't, so you build the compiler: but why do you trust the compiler binary to produce a trustworthy compiler?

Comment: He didn't actually do this; he merely claimed that it was possible. Never mind that doing step 2 reliably involves solving the halting problem (to determine whether source A is equivalent to source B, you must prove that they do the same, which includes determining whether both halt in the same circumstances)

Comment: @MSalters "The actual bug I planted in the compiler would match code in the UNIX "login" command."

Comment: @MSalters He did not attempt to insert on anything that might be a login command.  He made it insert for the actual code in the actual login command that was actually in Unix.  This is a much more tractable target, and his talk discusses exactly how to do that.

Comment: A compiler Y Combinator

Comment: This sort of problem is why some of us started programming with toggle switches :-)

Comment: @RossPatterson: Then you have to enter the paper-tape bootstrap with toggle switches also, and only use the tape you (personally) created.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens you mean you trust the hardware to interpret the toggle switches correctly? You're brave.